# Web view is too slow

Tags: flutter

Web view takes more than 4 sec to load the webpage. The same page takes less than 2 sec in Native app. Is there a way to speedup the load time. I tried both Official [webview_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) and [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin).

Answer (score 16):

If you app relies on WebView, just choose other tools: Swift for iOS & Kotlin for Android.

Here is why:

1. WebView actually does not load pages slow.  Instead, creating the WebView widget is slow;
2. In order to solve 1, you might want use a cached WebView.  Unfortunately, that is not easy.  Layout changes (e.g. animation) might trigger a WebView "recreating" (the cached WebView becomes invalid/staled).  And the "recreating" is very slow;
3. Flutter's widgets depend on "state" outside of the widgets, and widgets' creating are supposed to be fast/simple.  Unfortunately, WebView (which is not a native widget) is not the case.  WebView has its complex internal "state", a recreation simple discard everything and you returns to the WebView's initial state (initial URL).  And it is very slow (Creating time + LoadTime: Network overhead);
4. It is very hard to create a "external state" outside a WebView, therefore after a WebView's recreating it cannot resume from the external state;
5. Since WebView's recreating is very slow, it totally kills animation and gives user a very bad experience.  A solution might be put a WebView as your main page and never try to animate to a new WebView (just like a Wiki App Demo in YouTube).

Conclusion:

So, now, WebView in flutter is not ready and please don't consider use it seriously.

Discussion:

Flutter's widgets design is quite "unusual" since they are basically immutable.  States outside widgets (external state) are used.  When state changes, instead of modify the widget, Flutter choose to create a new widget based on the new state.  Therefore, widgets are deigned to be light weighted so they can be created/destroyed very quickly.  Unfortunately, WebView cannot fall into this category.  WebView is as complex as the whole Flutter framework, so it cannot be a native widget but a plug-in.  And WebView has its own internal state which is not compatible with the framework, which results in keep on being destroyed/recreated by the framework.

I am not sure why Flutter's widgets are designed in this way, maybe it is easier/faster for creating the framework?  I saw some complex examples (~100 lines) using Redux/BLOC/Steam just in order to "change" a widget, which might just need a one-line of code in other frameworks.

Performance is also an issue.  Rebuild a complex widgets tree is slow.  Then you need writing a lot of code (Redux/BLOC/Stream/ScoppedModel...) in order to implement a partial widgets tree build.

Even for a very simple app, performance of Flutter is still not as good as native (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/examining-performance-differences-between-native-flutter-and-react-native-mobile-development).  In fact, I'd like considering Flutter as "native" since it is compiled into machine code instead of Java's ByteCode.

Finally:

I am a new Flutter learner and start playing with Flutter for a couple of weeks.  The widgets framework and the WebView plug-in just made me headache.  A lot of time spent on the UI interface instead of the core logic of my app.

I am not saying Flutter is not good.  Actually, I think it is the best cross-platform framework for iOS/Android.  It just might be something (e.g. complex external widget like WebView) was not being taken into consideration while the framework was being designed.  Hope the Flutter team can find a solution for this, maybe a special case for handling a complex external plug-in?

I will keep on learning/playing with Flutter.

Comment: It's still too slow in 2020 even after of many updates, sadly to say.

Comment: The immutability of its widgets is actually one of Flutter's best design decisions. Redux always ends up with boilerplate which is a tradeoff, but it comes in super handy when you have a complex app with multiple developers and independent testing. You can basically completely test the states of your app without touching any user interface elements.

Comment: flutter is way more faster than its current competitives like react native or ionic or whatever. all cross-platforms have performance issues but between them, flutter is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

And now Hybrid-Composition is default in webview_flutter 3.0.0:
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/changelog

Just tried it on my side and since it's not perfect, it's much more faster

cheers!

Comment: webview_flutter 3.0.1 on Android gives me 10 seconds of download time vs 1 second in Chrome app on the same device. Not usable.

Comment: UPD: It turns out I was testing in debug; in release it gives me 4.5 seconds. Still too long :(

Comment: UPD2: For comparison, flutter_webview_plugin gives me 2 seconds in release which is better but still not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to `webview_flutter` 1.0.x and adopted `Hybrid-Composition`. It performances much better on Android now.

- Announcement: [announcing-flutter-1-22-44f146009e5f](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-22-44f146009e5f)
- How to: [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#using-hybrid-composition)
- Docs: [Hybrid-Composition](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hybrid-Composition)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
is to make the Webview faster. We need to disable hybrid composition. For this, make the changes in the InAppWebView group options as below:

```
...
InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: false,
    ),
  );
...
```

Hybrid composition makes the widget load slower in Android versions below 10. So, making this false will make the widgets load faster in the lower versions of android. Although it does not makes the in app web view fully fast as in app web view uses lot of resources so its by default slower. But this can help to get some faster output upto certain level. This solution is mentioned in detail in the in app web view official document, you can refer it in detail here: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/in-app-webview